# Struts 2 - Submit button onclick trigger issue

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have a Struts `<s:submit>` button in the form and when I click the button, the page should remain the same, so I added an `onclick` function to the submit button:

```jsp
<s:submit action="product" method="loadsearch" id="find" onclick="return false"/>
```

Why is the submit button not triggering a submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be on the same page needs to make Ajax call, as far as you using struts2-jquery plugin it's easy done via

place it on the JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags" %> 
<head>
 <sj:head/>
</head>

<s:div id="result"/>

<s:form action="product" method="POST"/>
  <sj:submit method="loadsearch" id="find" targets="result" />
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you `return false` which cancels submission.

Comment: Okay , I suppose to submit the form but it should not forward to another page, then i have to use ajax call or struts2-jquery submit button ?